# Make UILabel auto-adjust font size to screen width, but not to text length

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

In a very simple single screen app, I have a single-line UILabel going from left edge to right edge of the screen. 
The text of the label is dynamically updated at runtime. The length of the text varies, as it contains a number in the range 0...100, and I am neither using a monospaced font nor leading zeroes.

Here is an illustration:

```
    |<--------- Screen width --------------->|

    |<----- UILabel "Some value = 0" ------->|

    |<----- UILabel "Some value = 50" ------>|

    |<----- UILabel "Some value = 100" ----->|
```

I would like the label to always use the maximum width for any device (i.e. screen size). This can be achieved by using auto-layout, suitable leading and trailing constraints, a large font size and the "auto-shrink" property for the label.

The problem is, that this approach will make the font size also vary depending on the value displayed, which is not what I want. It should only vary with the width of the screen, but not with the length of the label text.

In the example above, a large font size would be used for the value 0, a medium one for 50 and a small one for 100. I want it to adjust to the worst-case (100) and use the resulting size for any text afterwards.

Is it possible to achieve this using Interface-Builder properties and auto-layout constraints only?

I can think of ways how to calculate sizes in code, but I think there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot express font size as a proportion of view width in interface builder but you can do it very easily in code:

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let textSize = Constant.baseFontSize * bounds.size.width / Constant.baseViewWidth
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: textSize)
  }
```